# How can I set the android preference summary text color?

Tags: android, text, colors, summary, preference

On my preference screen I have a preference that when clicked opens a color picker dialog.  What I would like to do is when the user selects a color, that the text summary of the preference is displayed in that color.

I know I can have the summary set up like this, `Currently <font color="#ff0000">this color</font>` and have it display in that color.  The problem is the color I am getting back is the android int color.

I could use the red(), green(), blue() methods and then convert those to Hex and then combine them into a string so I could set the summary text with the new value and that works: `String colorString = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x",Color.red( defaultColor ), Color.green( defaultColor ), Color.blue( defaultColor ));` I was just curious if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks ahead of time.

Sean

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OK what I ended up doing was using a Spannable.  This takes the color as an integer.

```
Spannable summary = new SpannableString("Currently This Color");
summary.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, summary.length(), 0);
preference.setSummary(summary);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Html.fromHtml to style your text.

```
mPodFolderPref.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>" +  mPodFolderPref.getTitle() + "</font>"));
mPodFolderPref.setSummary(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>" +  mPodFolderPref.getSummary() + "</font>"));
```

Html.fromHtml can do a lot for you.

Comment: Not sure why it's being downvoted but this is the simplest answer to the question and easiest to implement.

Comment: The .fromHtml-solution also allows you to change lots of attributes more than just the textcolor, such as <b></b> to bold the text. Hence, it is the much more valuable answer for me. Upvoted.

Comment: Its depreciated.

Comment: This works, but I think it doesn't work for ListPreference

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I found useful to write these self-contained methods:

```
private void setColorPreferencesTitle(EditTextPreference textPref, int color) {
    CharSequence cs     = (CharSequence) textPref.getTitle();
    String plainTitle   = cs.subSequence(0, cs.length()).toString();
    Spannable coloredTitle = new SpannableString (plainTitle);
    coloredTitle.setSpan( new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, coloredTitle.length(), 0 );
    textPref.setTitle(coloredTitle);
}

private void resetColorPreferencesTitle(EditTextPreference textPref) {
    CharSequence cs     = (CharSequence) textPref.getTitle();
    String plainTitle   = cs.subSequence(0, cs.length()).toString();
    textPref.setTitle(plainTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All the above ways didn't help me. I ended up by extends the Prefernces class:

```
public class CustomListPreferences extends Preference {

    public CustomListPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomListPreferences(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
       ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.summary)).setTextColor(getContext().get Resources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can change the color of preference using Html.fromHtml().

ex : private String title = "" + "Set the SMS Send Limit" + "";

and add set this string from your android application like this .

CheckBoxPreference _test = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("text");
_test .setTitle(Html.fromHtml(title ));

follow this link for html view of android :
http://www.androidpeople.com/tag/html-tags/

Thanks

Comment: I am aware of that.  However, like I said above, I have access to the color as an int which is how Android stores it.  Not the RGB or ARGB strings.