# Is there a way to dynamically change the preference screen font color?

Tags: android

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334828/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-prefernce-screen) works lovely for doing it once statically.

But what if I have a font color preference, and I want the preference screen itself to update based on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with the information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4005029/1101070) answer, you could try using a `SpannableString` object and set the color that way. The example from that answer:

```
Spannable summary = new SpannableString ("Currently This Color");
summary.setSpan( new ForgroundColorSpan(color), 0, summary.length(), 0 );
preference.setSummary(summary);
```

Comment: My mistake. This helps me a lot. My color is not a color int but a resource int, I didn't convert it at first, I should use

`new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark))`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to this: [Android PreferenceScreen title in two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220039/android-preferencescreen-title-in-two-lines/20291526#20291526).

Add this:

```
if (textView != null) {
    textView.setTextColor(textView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
}
```